# Calculating ECDSA signature in Java as per an RFC test vector

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I am writing a test harness in java for a program relating to the ikev2 protocol.  As part of this i need to be able to calculate an ECDSA signature (specifically using the NIST P-256 curve).

[RFC 4754](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4754) Describes the the use of ECDSA in IKEv2 and helpfully provides a set of test vectors (Including for the p256 curve that i need).

I am trying to run the ECDSA-256 Test Vector values ([Section 8.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4754#section-8.1) in the RFC) through java's ECDSA signature implementation using the following code:

```
//"abc" for the input
byte[] input = { 0x61, 0x62, 0x63 };

//Ugly way of getting the ECParameterSpec for the P-256 curve by name as opposed to specifying all the parameters manually.
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
ECGenParameterSpec kpgparams = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
kpg.initialize(kpgparams);
ECParameterSpec params = ((ECPublicKey) kpg.generateKeyPair().getPublic()).getParams();

//Create the static private key W from the Test Vector
ECPrivateKeySpec static_privates = new ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger("DC51D3866A15BACDE33D96F992FCA99DA7E6EF0934E7097559C27F1614C88A7F", 16), params);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
ECPrivateKey spriv = (ECPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(static_privates);

//Perfrom ECDSA signature of the data with SHA-256 as the hash algorithm
Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
dsa.initSign(spriv);
dsa.update(input);

byte[] output = dsa.sign();
System.out.println("Result: " + new BigInteger(1, output).toString(16));
```

The result should be:

> CB28E099 9B9C7715 FD0A80D8 E47A7707 9716CBBF 917DD72E
> 97566EA1 C066957C 86FA3BB4 E26CAD5B F90B7F81 899256CE 7594BB1E A0C89212
> 748BFF3B 3D5B0315

Instead I get:

> 30460221 00dd9131 edeb5efd c5e718df c8a7ab2d 5532b85b 7d4c012a e5a4e90c 3b824ab5 d7022100 9a8a2b12 9e10a2ff 7066ff79 89aa73d5 ba37c868 5ec36517 216e2e43 ffa876d7

I know that the length difference is due to Java ASN.1 Encoding the signature. However, the rest of it is completely wrong and I'm stumped as to why.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

P.S I am not a ECDSA or Java crypto expert so it is probably a stupid mistake I am making

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing that each time you run your program, you get a different signature value for the same plaintext (to-be-signed) input.

ECDSA specifies that a random ephemeral ECDSA private key be generated per signature. To that end, `Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA")` doesn't let you specify an ephemeral key (this is a good thing, to prevent many a self shot in the foot!). Instead, it gets its own SecureRandom instance that will make your output nondeterministic.

This probably means you can't use JCE (`Signature.getInstance()`) for test vector validation.

What you could do is extend `SecureRandom` in a way that it returns deterministic data. Obviously you shouldn't use this in a real deployment:

```
public class FixedSecureRandom extends SecureRandom {
    private static boolean debug = false;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public FixedSecureRandom() { }
    private int nextBytesIndex = 0;

    private byte[] nextBytesValues = null;

    public void setBytes(byte[] values) {
        this.nextBytesValues = values; 
    }

    public void nextBytes(byte[] b) {
        if (nextBytesValues==null) { 
            super.nextBytes(b);
        } else if (nextBytesValues.length==0) { 
            super.nextBytes(b);
        } else {
            for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
                b[i] = nextBytesValues[nextBytesIndex];
                nextBytesIndex = (nextBytesIndex + 1) % nextBytesValues.length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Phew. Ok now you have a SecureRandom class that returns you some number of known bytes, then falls back to a real SecureRandom after that. I'll say it again (excuse the shouting) - DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION!

Next you'll need to use a ECDSA implementation that lets you specify your own SecureRandom. You can use BouncyCastle's `ECDSASigner` for this purpose. Except here you're going to give it your own bootlegged FixedSecureRandom, so that when it calls `secureRandom.getBytes()`, it gets the bytes you want it to.  This lets you control the ephemeral key to match that specified in the test vectors. You may need to massage the actual bytes (eg. add zero pre-padding) to match what `ECDSASigner` is going to request.

```
ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPriv = ...; // this is the user's EC private key (not ephemeral)

FixedSecureRandom fsr_k = new FixedSecureRandom();
fsr_k.setBytes(tempKeyK);

ECDSASigner signer = new ECDSASigner();
ParametersWithRandom ecdsaprivrand = new ParametersWithRandom(ecPriv, fsr_k);
signer.init(true, ecdsaprivrand);
```

Note that BC's `ECDSASigner` implements only the EC signature part, not the hashing. You'll still need to do your own hashing (assuming your input data is in `data`):

```
Digest md = new SHA256Digest()
md.reset();
md.update(data, 0, data.length);
byte[] hash = new byte[md.getDigestSize()];
md.doFinal(hash, 0);
```

before you create the ECDSA signature:

```
BigInteger[] sig = signer.generateSignature(hash);
```

Finally, this `BigInteger[]` (should be length==2) are the (r,s) values. You'll need to ASN.1 DER-encode it, which should give you the <strike>droids</strike> bytes you're looking for.

Comment: Success! Thanks for the speedy and very detailed answer. As soon as i read it it made sense and its all working for me now.  Huge thanks for your help :-)

Comment: P.S For anyone else looking at this.  I initially made the rookie mistake of doing fsr_k.setBytes(new BigInteger("9E56F509196784D963D1C0A401510EE7ADA3DCC5DEE04B154BF61AF1D5A6DECE", 16).toByteArray()) and nearly cried.  In doing this an extra 0 byte is prepended to the byte array and so you still end up with the wrong K value :-(

Comment: @PinkyNoBrain You need a function called I2OS (integer to octet string). This method takes *two* inputs, an integer and (key) length. It returns the unsigned big endian encoding of the integer, with `00` bytes prepended up to the key size. You now have the unsigned part, make sure you have the padding part as well...

Comment: Thanks a million for: ECDSASigner implements only the EC signature part, not the hashing.

Answer (score 1):

here's my complete test following tsechin's solution using BouncyCastle but sticking to good old JCA API:

```
    byte[] input = { 0x61, 0x62, 0x63 };

    //Create the static private key W from the Test Vector
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec parameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1");
    org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger("DC51D3866A15BACDE33D96F992FCA99DA7E6EF0934E7097559C27F1614C88A7F", 16), parameterSpec);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    ECPrivateKey spriv = (ECPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

    //Perfrom ECDSA signature of the data with SHA-256 as the hash algorithm
    Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC");
    FixedSecureRandom random = new FixedSecureRandom();
    random.setBytes(Hex.decode("9E56F509196784D963D1C0A401510EE7ADA3DCC5DEE04B154BF61AF1D5A6DECE"));
    dsa.initSign(spriv, random);
    dsa.update(input);
    byte[] output = dsa.sign();

    // compare the signature with the expected reference values
    ASN1Sequence sequence = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(output);
    DERInteger r = (DERInteger) sequence.getObjectAt(0);
    DERInteger s = (DERInteger) sequence.getObjectAt(1);
    Assert.assertEquals(r.getValue(), new BigInteger("CB28E0999B9C7715FD0A80D8E47A77079716CBBF917DD72E97566EA1C066957C", 16));
    Assert.assertEquals(s.getValue(), new BigInteger("86FA3BB4E26CAD5BF90B7F81899256CE7594BB1EA0C89212748BFF3B3D5B0315", 16));
```

Comment: help, me. I executing `ECPrivateKey spriv = (ECPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);` makes app ignore the rest of code